# Surface Pro 3 Dock - Blinking light, no charge

Tags: battery, dock, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I have a Surface Pro 3 and a dock. When I attach the Surface to the dock, the indicator light blinks and will not charge the device:

Steps I have taken:

- Ran and installed all Windows updates with the dock attached
- Power cycled the Dock
- Disconnected all devices (monitor) from the Dock

And still all I have is a blinking light.

Comment: Same thing. On Windows that came with device it won't charge at all. But after updating to 1709 it charges but still blinks and no accessory on it is recognized